# Rails 4: Authorizing Users to View, Edit, and Delete Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization

I want anyone (even those not logged in) to be able to view the posts, but only the owner of the post to be able to edit or destroy the post. Currently, however, any user can edit or destroy any post. If I change

```
def set_pin
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
end
```

to

```
def set_pin
  @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
end
```

the current user cannot edit other users' posts, but also cannot view them. Please help me out. Thanks.

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

  # GET /pins
  # GET /pins.json
  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  # GET /pins/1
  # GET /pins/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /pins/new
  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.new
  end

  # GET /pins/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /pins
  # POST /pins.json
  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(pin_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1
  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.update(pin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pins/1
  # DELETE /pins/1.json
  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pins_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for edit and destroy use

```
def set_pin
  @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Like I said, this works for edit and destroy but "show" only works for the owner of the post as well. I want anyone to be able to view the posts.

Comment: you can create two separate function set_pin and set_pin_self one for show and one for edit and destroy and use Pin.find(params[:id]) and current_user.pins.find(params[:id]) alternatively